# Computed property is not updating

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, drop-down-menu

I have data in vue

```
newContract: {
  latest_contract: false,
  invoicing_period: "",
}
```

in computed method I am applying different properties to **this.newContract.invoicing_period**

```
computed: {
  invoicing_period() {
    const period = this.newContract.invoicing_period
    const monthToPct = {
      1615: "mid_month",
      calendarMonth: "calendar_month",
    };
    return monthToPct[period];
  }
}
```

and in methods I am appending **this.invoicing_period** from computed

```
let fd = new FormData();
fd.append("latest_contract", newContract.latest_contract);
fd.append("invoicing_period", this.invoicing_period);
```

in HTML I have a select dropdown.

```
<select
  id="invoicingDropdown"
  name="invoicingPperiod"
  v-model="newContract.invoicing_period"
  >
  <option selected value="1615">15./16.</option>
  <option value="calendarMonth">30/31.</option>
</select>
```

The problem is, that I am sending the correct values after choosing the options from dropdown, but it is not updating the **newContract.invoicing_period** from vue data().

Thank you.

Comment: Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/039bvq7t/, seems to work for me. What exactly isn't working how it needs to?

Comment: This is also working for me but in Vue data  `newContract: 
{
  latest_contract: false,
  invoicing_period: "",
}`   invoicing_period is not updating but stays empty string.

Comment: There may be an error being caused by `newContract.latest_contract` not having `this.` before it in your method

Comment: I am appending it like this `fd.append("invoicing_period", this.invoicing_period)`.

Comment: Do you think `newContract.latest_contract` has something to do with another property? I am using  `this.invoicing_period` because it comes from computed method, `newContract.latest_contract` is just from Vue data and works without `this`.

Comment: i doubt that works. If you are not using `this` you are using a global variable or something else. The only place where you do not need `this` is in the template itself.

Comment: @Nitsa Can you share a link to a fiddle that reproduces the problem?